# Why must two subgroups with trivial intersection commute with one another?

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

I've been struggling with this proof lately. It says

> Let $M$ and $N$ be normal subgroups of a group $G$ such that $M\cap N=\langle e\rangle $. If $a \in M$ and $b \in N$ then $ab=ba$.

The proof starts with

> [...] consider $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$. Since $M$ is normal, $b^{-1}ab \in M$; similarly normality in $N$ implies that $a^{-1}b^{-1}a \in N$.

What leaves me confused is the above statement : how can I know that $b^{-1}ab \in M$ and how can I know that $a^{-1}b^{-1}a \in N$, and why is it not the other way around?

Comment: Because they must stay in the one where the element in the middle is.

Comment: is it from $a^{-1}Na \subset N$ for every $a \in G$?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Note that: $\forall a \in M: b^{-1} a b \in M$, since $M$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. (That is the definition of a subgroup). Likewise: $\forall b \in N: a^{-1} b a \in N$, since $N$ is a normal subgroup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subgroup $M$ is normal in $G$ if and only if, for every $x\in M$ and every $g\in G$, $g^{-1}xg\in M$.

In your case, you can consider, for $a\in M$ and $b\in N$ (so also $b^{-1}\in N$),
$$
a^{-1}b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}\underbrace{(b^{-1}ab)}_{\in M}\in M
$$
and
$$
a^{-1}b^{-1}ab=\underbrace{(a^{-1}b^{-1}a)}_{\in N}\,b\in N
$$
because $M$ and $N$ are subgroups, so closed under products.

Therefore $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab\in M\cap N$ and so, by assumption, $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab=e$. Hence
$$
ba(a^{-1}b^{-1}ab)=bae
$$
which means $ab=ba$.